# How to get more info from AVFoundationError

Tags: swift, avfoundation, avassetexportsession, nserror

I am trying to debug my "videoGenerator" class; which is a class that takes video URLs and audio URLs and merges them together with AVFoundation. When trying to combine some videos with music I get the following error from my exportSession:

`Error Domain=AVFoundationErrorDomain Code=-11838 "Operation Stopped" UserInfo={NSLocalizedFailureReason=The operation is not supported for this media., NSLocalizedDescription=Operation Stopped, NSUnderlyingError=0x600003f089f0 {Error Domain=NSOSStatusErrorDomain Code=-16976 "(null)"}}`

I need to know more than this, and I see that within the error there is a memory address:

`NSUnderlyingError=0x600003f089f0`

I am wondering if this might hold more info about what exactly is wrong with the media types.

My question is, how can I get something human readable from this memory address within Xcode console other than using `$arg1` or is that my only option?

Comment: "This is really not very useful"  Your question is not very intuitive, either.  You want somebody to analyze your error message without even telling what has led to that error?  What is 'videoGenerator'?

Comment: Updated the question to be more clear

Comment: The error if pretty explicit: "The operation is not supported for this media." This is AVErrorOperationNotSupportedForAsset. I would look at the operation you're trying to perform, and the specific asset type (including format) that you're trying to perform it on, and your answer is likely there. Without details of what you're doing, we are unlikely to be able to help you here.

Answer (score 3):

This question is was really more for me about how to debug this, not so much about what the actually issue was that prevented export. Was able to find the method [determineCompatibleFileTypes](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avassetexportsession/1387907-determinecompatiblefiletypes) on `AVAssetExportSession`. This method reports the formats that the input files can be exported to. Turns out an export session cannot export .mp3 files into .mp4 or .m4v formats, a simple check prior to export fixes this issue:

```
           exportSession.determineCompatibleFileTypes { (fileTypes) in
                if fileTypes.contains(.m4v) {
                    exportSession.outputFileType = .m4v
                } else {
                    exportSession.outputFileType = .mov
                }
            }
```

We have sort of tight control on what our incoming media types are so this level of simplicity works for us, however, this could easily be expanded to suit a more complex variety.

[Rob Napier's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/97337/rob-napier) comment was really pretty spot on, in that the answer ultimately doesn't lie in the `NSUnderlyingError=0x600003f089f0` portion of this error, but instead in the description. My issue was more that I did not read the error and understand initially that it was pointing to the fact that the media I was giving the session was not supported for the media I was asking for from the session.

Hopefully this will help someone else who is new to the AV apis in swift like I am, this took me days to track down :)

Thanks to anyone who took a look, or left a comment!